# AccountShare delete issue

Tags: apex, soql, account, sharing, accountshare

I'm trying to delete all AccountShare records, but getting the below error:

> SHARE_NEEDED_FOR_CHILD_OWNER, account share row needed for owner or
> share of at least

I tried adding `order by` inside my query in order to delete the child sharing first but still didn't help. How can I overcome this issue?

I use the below query:

```
SELECT Id, AccountId, Account.ParentId FROM AccountShare WHERE UserOrGroupId IN usersList ORDER BY Account.ParentId DESC NULLS LAST
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query is not specific enough. There are some types of shares you cannot manually delete, such as Owner, Team Member, Sharing Rules, etc. You can try deleting them with the allOrNone=false option to delete as many as possible, or filter the query to include only Manual shares (these are the only types you can directly delete).

Comment: How can I specify to delete only manual shares? I understand that it should be based on the RowCause field and set it as "Manual"?

Comment: @MichałPastuszka Correct.